# how to estimate the precipitation value from other relative data

Tags: mathematical-statistics, data-transformation, data-imputation, climate, environmental-data

I have climate data but the precipitation values are missing,
I would like to know if there is any formula used to estimate the precipitation value from the other recorded climate data: temperature, dew point and humidity.

Thanks.

Comment: Since precipitation is *weather* (very short-term climate) you will want to have other weather data, not climate data, to predict the missing precipitation values.  But--knowing a little bit about weather--I doubt you will achieve accurate predictions of precipitation *amounts* from just temp, dew point, and humidity.  But maybe you could infer precipitation *events.* This raises two  questions: exactly what precipitation "value" are you interested in and what is the temporal frequency of the data you have?

Comment: I have a daily data.